# Probability of 2 discrete samples coming from same distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, discrete-distributions

I would like to know how to calculate the probability that 2 discrete samples come from the same distribution, and if so, which one is the distribution they are coming from.

Let's say we have 3 buckets, and 2 years.

| Bucket\year | 2019 | 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 76% | 73% |
| B | 20% | 22% |
| C | 4% | 5% |

I would like to claim that they both come from the same distribution (which I'd assume is close to [74.5%,21%,4.5%]) and that the variation between years is just given by random chance (with which probability?). I think in order to make this claim I have to calculate the probability that both samples come from the same distribution (I heard about 'power' for continous random variables, but I don't know if there's an equivalent in discrete verison). Any hint on how to proceed?

Thanks a lot!

As side note: both periods of time have different amount of datapoints, ie. 2019 has 350, 2020 has 400. Is it too much of a problem?

Comment: Knowing the number of data points is essential (it makes a big difference to a significance test between them being hundreds or being millions) but them changing between years is not a problem.  A chi-square test on the counts  (preferably unrounded) rather than proportions may meet your needs

Comment: Thanks Henry!

So the Chi-square needs a Null-hypothesis. What would it be in this scenario? 
I could assume that the 'real' distribution is the one of 2019, 2020, or the global (generated using data from both years)

Comment: The third option is the appropriate one. Under the null hypothesis (no difference between 2019 and 2020) you can combine the data from the two years.

Comment: Unless you assume a prior probability, the answer is definitely no, no matter what.  The kind of question you *could* answer with something like a chi-squared test concerns how consistent the data are with a hypothetical common distribution.   Different numbers of data points are no problem, but the degree to which different data might be *independent* is a key consideration, especially when data are collected over time.